# How to save a word file (Docx) to a single HTML page?

Tags: html, microsoft-word

I am using Word 2016, I want to save a Word document as an HTML page.

I want to save the html as a single page without any files.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Word **Save As**, select the **Save As type** as Web Page, Filtered.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click File > Save As and choose the location where you want to save your
   document.
2. Name your file.
3. In the Save as type list, choose Web Page, Filtered.
4. Click Change Title and type the title you want to display in a web
   browser’s title bar.
5. Click Save.

or visit this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/save-a-document-as-a-webpage-d1cf1c33-e854-4f9d-bd51-93f94da0f4e3